# Using EntityFrameWorkCore and SqlLite in memory I get "no such table: ControlGroup" error

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

The context of my problem is, I want to create some unit tests to my application which executes some relational-specific code, so I can't use the standard `.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: dbContextName)` I changed it to `.UseSqlite("DataSource=:memory:")` instead in order to fix that.

But now I get:

> SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: ControlGroup'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check that table ControlGroup exists in the database?

Comment: I don't really know how to check that since its an in memory db. I believe the problem is caused because when the database connection is closed the database is cleared

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to keep the connection open within your test scope and create the database.

```
public class Tests : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqliteConnection _connection;
    private readonly DbContextOptions _options;

    public Tests()
    {
        _connection = new SqliteConnection("datasource=:memory:");
        _connection.Open();

        _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
            .UseSqlite(_connection)
            .Options;

        using (var context = new MyContext(_options))
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext(_options))
        {
            // use in memory database
            context.ControlGroup ...
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I was aware of having to keep my connection open, the context.Database.EnsureCreated(); is the key for this problem (when changing from inMemory to SqlLite in memory too) I think you could update your response to highlight that and make it more obvious for people having the same problem to be able to see it faster

Comment: btw I was following this tutorial https://www.meziantou.net/2017/09/11/testing-ef-core-in-memory-using-sqlite it might help other people with the same issue